# Multibinding not firing when the bound properties change

Tags: wpf, data-binding, multibinding

I have a wpf wpplication with a number of user controls in it.  One of these controls has a property called `ButtonsEnabled`.  This is a bool DependencyProperty in the user control.  The property is bound to the IsEnabled property of a couple of buttons on that control.

This user control is used in the `MainWindow`.  The `MainWindow` has a couple of view model objects in it called `EocMonitor` and `ComMonitor`.  These both descend from an abstract base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  The `ButtonsEnabled` property on the UserControl is bound to the `Status` property using a multibinding and a class that implements `IMultiConverter` that I wrote.

The problem is that even though the PropertyChanged event is being raised when the `Status` property changes, the IMultiConverter is not being called after it is initially called, so the value of the `ButtonsEnabled` property is not changing.  As a result, the buttons are not enabling.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: add source code and it will be easy for SO to say you what do you need.

Comment: You probably have to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`. I cannot be certain as you haven't posted any source code!

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger` was set to `PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an end-run around this problem as I am running out of time before we reach our code-freeze for this release.  What I did was I added a `ButtonsEnabled` `DepdendencyProperty` to the `MainWindow` class and bound it to the user control's `ButtonsEnabled` property.  I then added a `PropertyChanged` event handler in the MainWindow and and registered it with the `DbMonitor` and `ComMonitor` objects when they were created.  I then wrote code in the `PropertyChanged` event handler to set the `MainWindow`'s `ButtonsEnabled` properly.

Everything works and I'll worry about making the other approach work at some later time.  Maybe.